# page is not scrolling to top on click of button

Tags: reactjs

I want to scroll to the top of page on click of a button but its not happening
code-

```
export default class productdetail extends Component {
  scrollToTop(){
    window.scrollTo({ 
      top: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth'
     });
  }
  actionForProducts(product){
     return(
       <div>
         <button className="add_cart btn  rounded-pill w-100  " onClick={this.scrollToTop}>
            Scroll to top
          </button>
       </div>
    )
  }
  render(){
    return(
       <div className=" h-100  detail_page">
         {this.renderProduct(this.props.productdetail)}
        </div>
    )

}
```

when i am trying to console something then it prints i guess this window.scrollTo have some problem.

Comment: The scrollto code seems to be correct. Check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-glitter-zf529?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please show demo in codesandbox